# Python: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, reduce

say a list of tuples like this:

```
y=[('a', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'c', 'b'),
 ('b', 'a', 'c'),
 ('b', 'c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a', 'b'),
 ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

I am trying to use reduce() feature to make a string of each element in y.
''.join(list(x) gives lets say 'abc' for first iteration.

```
z=reduce(lambda x, u=dict(): u.setdefault(''.join(list(x)), []).extend(''.join(list(x))), y)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-79858e678e78> in <module>()
----> 1 z=reduce(lambda x, u=dict(): u.setdefault(''.join(list(x)), []).extend(''.join(list(x))), y)

<ipython-input-102-79858e678e78> in <lambda>(x, u)
----> 1 z=reduce(lambda x, u=dict(): u.setdefault(''.join(list(x)), []).extend(''.join(list(x))), y)

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters u
{}

print u
{}

Comment: @MartijnPieters why is it not running? isnt it taking from the iterator, the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduce()` is called with 2 arguments *always*, so your `u` argument is set to the second value in `y`, a tuple.  The default is ignored.

You really shouldn't use `reduce()` here. `reduce()` you need when you want to use the *next* element in the iterator for each loop iteration to calculate one aggregate value.

You are *mapping* instead:

```
map(''.join, y)
```

or use a list comprehension:

```
[''.join(x) for x in y]
```

Comment: ok i thought as in http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce i have to use reduce(lambda arg1,arg2, do_something(arg1,arg2), y)

Comment: ok. Thanks I will use map. Just By the way, is it possible with reduce() ?

Comment: @user2290820: Not for this job; `reduce()` takes an iterable and 'reduces' the elements down to one. `reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, [1, 2, 3, 4])` would sum all the elements of the list, starting with `1` and `2`, then call the lambda again with the result of the first call and the next element, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Not clear why reduce in involved. Are you looking for:

```
[''.join(t) for t in y]
```

Comment: I got confused also and came up with  an ` z = [ "".join(item) for item in y] ` then you posted this +1